# AttributeError: 'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute '_assert_compile_was_called' google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-classification

```
model_fit = model.fit(Train_dataset,
    validation_data=Val_dataset, 
  steps_per_epoch=5, epochs=10)
```

I tried this code snippet and getting an error saying "AttributeError: 'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute '_assert_compile_was_called'". I tried downgrading the tensorflow version, but it's not working.

Comment: Can you please share a standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: Hey TFer2, that issue got resolved. But thanks for asking.

Comment: That's good to hear. For the benefit of the community please post your solution in the answer section. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, Actually I changed my solution. I used fastai for the classification.